# Find the set ∆X

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus

Let $X = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$, and $\Delta X = \{(x,x)~:~x\in X\}$.

Find the set $\Delta X$.

\begin{align}
    \Delta X=\{&(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (0,4),\\
& (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4),\\
& (2,0), (2,1),(2,2), (2,3), (2,4),\\
& (3,0), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (3,4),\\
& (4,0), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4)\}
\end{align}
Have I correctly found set $\Delta X$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: No, that's  $X\times{X}$.

Comment: Note the difference between $\{(x,x)~:~x\in X\}$ where both elements in a pair must be the same and $\{(x,y)~:~x\in X,~y\in X\}$ where the elements in a pair could be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set $\Delta X$ is incorrect. Note that in the definition of $\Delta X$, each member of this set is of the form $(x,x)$, so the entries in the pair must be the same. This means $\Delta X$ cannot contain elements like $(0,1)$. The answer is

$$\Delta X = \{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$$